# Program Error, Due to the use of std::unique_ptr in VS2010?

Tags: c++

I been writing a program in which, an array will dynamically grow when ever the max size is reach. I have used std::unique_ptr, but I'm not sure what is causing the error. I'm using VS2010.

The error is: 
*error C2027: use of undefined type 'DyArray::Impl' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\memory   2067*

Here is the code

**DyArray.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class DyArray
{
public:
    DyArray(int IntialSize, int IncrementSize)
    {
    }
    ~DyArray()
    {
    }
    void Insert(int Data);
    void Set(int Position,int Data);
    int Get(int Position);
    void Print();
private:
    DyArray(const DyArray&);
    DyArray& operator=(const DyArray&);
    struct Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_Impl;
};
```

**DyArray.cpp**

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>

struct DyArray::Impl
{
    typedef struct
    {
        int* array;
        size_t used;
        size_t size;
    }Array;

public:
    Array* m_DyArray;
    size_t m_InitalSize;
    size_t m_IncrementSize;

    Impl(Array* DyArray,int IntialSize,int IncrementSize):m_DyArray(DyArray),m_InitalSize(IntialSize),m_IncrementSize(IncrementSize)
    {
        m_DyArray->array = (int*)malloc(m_InitalSize * sizeof(int));
        m_DyArray->used = 0;
        m_DyArray->size = m_InitalSize;
    }

    ~Impl()
    {
        free(m_DyArray->array);
        m_DyArray->array = NULL;
        m_DyArray->used = m_DyArray->size = 0;
    }

    void insertArray(int element)
    {
        if (m_DyArray->used == m_DyArray->size)
        {
            m_DyArray->size += m_IncrementSize;
            m_DyArray->array = (int*)realloc(m_DyArray->array,m_DyArray->size*sizeof(int));
        }
        m_DyArray->array[m_DyArray->used++] = element;
    }

    void Display()
    {
        std::cout<<"\n";
        for (int i = 0; i< m_DyArray->used;i++)
        {
            std::cout<<m_DyArray->array[i]<<" ";
        }
    }
};

void DyArray::Insert( int Data )
{
    m_Impl->insertArray(Data);
}

void DyArray::Print()
{
    m_Impl->Display();
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "DyArray.h"
#include <iostream>

void main()
{
    DyArray dyarray(2,3);
    dyarray.Insert(12);
    dyarray.Insert(14);
    dyarray.Insert(55);
    dyarray.Insert(23);
    dyarray.Insert(444);
    dyarray.Insert(23);

    dyarray.Print();
}
```

Comment: You really should just use `std::vector` but I presume you will respond "but this is homework" in which case you really should take the time to learn what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructor of your class needs to destroy the unique pointer, which in turn needs to delete the `Impl` it manages. It can only do that if `Impl` is a complete (i.e. fully defined) type.

Define the destructor in the source file, after the definition of `Impl`, not in the class definition.

You'll also need to define the constructor there, if you want it to create an `Impl` and initialise the pointer.

Comment: I think there's a "destructor" that should be "constructor" in your last paragraph.